# Showing $\left | d\left ( u,v \right )-d\left ( w,x \right ) \right |\leq d\left ( u,w \right )+d\left ( v,x \right )$

Tags: metric-spaces, absolute-value

> Lemma:
>
> Let $u,v,w,x \in X$.
> Then, $\left | d\left ( u,v \right )-d\left ( w,x \right ) \right |\leq d\left ( u,w \right )+d\left ( v,x \right )$

By the triangle inequality:

$d\left ( u,v \right )-d\left ( w,x \right )\leq d\left ( u,w \right )+d\left ( x,v \right )$
and
$d\left ( w,x \right )-d\left ( u,v \right )\leq d\left ( w,u \right )+d\left ( v,x \right )$

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might use that $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ $\forall x, y \in X$ ("symmetry") and that $d(x,y) ≥ 0$ $\forall x,y \in X$ ("non-negativity").

Answer (score 0):

Using the triangle inequality (and the symmetrie of your metric $d$) is already enought since 
$$|x|\leq c \qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad -x \leq c \ \text{and} \ x\leq c.$$